# Storing files in wwwroot folder vs storing in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have a project ASP.Net MVC classics which need to be migrated to Azure and host in AppServices. Currently this project save files in the root folder and file size could be 2GB.

Now the question is should I leave the current logic to store the file in wwwroot folder as:\wwwroot\Files\myfile.txt"; or should I store it in the blob?

I am looking for the best practice and do not want to change the current logic? Can someone give me the idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Storing files in Azure Blob Storage:***

- According to [Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/storage/blobs/#overview) it says,

> Azure Blob Storage enables the creation of data lakes for analytics purposes and provides storage for the development of powerful cloud-native and mobile apps. Reduce costs by using tiered storage for long-term data and scalability for high-performance computing and machine learning workloads.

- According to [Documentation](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/uploading-files-to-azure-blob-storage-with-shared-access-signature-sas) it says,

> SAS enables you to securely upload and download files from Azure Blob Storage without having to share the connection string.

- While uploading you can split large data in small amounts with which we can decrease uploading time and after uploading then it again combines into a single blob.

***Storing file in wwwroot folder:***

- According to [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-static-files) it says

> Static resource files are stored in web root, The default  directory is ***{content root}/wwwroot***  folder.

- According to [Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) we can clearly say that capacity depends on price tier.
- Web apps performance can be effected by uploading large files.
- In Azure linux web apps, if the size is around 2 Gb then it might lead to  timeoutException.